# Is there any way to print hexadecimal and bytes in label widget in tkinter python?

Tags: python, tkinter, label

I have been working on a class project to write an encryption code in python. I have used AES encryption. But now while creating a graphical interface using Tkinter, I can't print ciphered text as it is in hexadecimal. If anyone knows how to print hexadecimal or bytes in the label widget in Tkinter then please let me know. Thanks.

```
ciphertext = ciphertext + list(encrypt(plaintext.encode(), key, AES.MODE_ECB))
cipher_label = Label(win, text='Cipher: ' + binascii.hexlify(bytes(ciphertext)))
cipher_label.place(x=80, y=270)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`binascii.hexlify(bytes(ciphertext))` returns another `bytes` object with the corresponding hexadecimal inside. You're looking for `bytes(ciphertext).hex()` to get a string representation.

Comment: Thanks, it worked. I have one more issue with my code:
This is my for loop for brute force:
  for passw in passwords:
        key = hashlib.sha256(passw.encode()).digest()
        plaintext = decrypt(bytes(ciphertext), key, AES.MODE_ECB)
        plaintext_label = Label(win, text=plaintext)
        plaintext_label.place(x=80, y=360)
        if isprintable(plaintext):
            p = Padding.removePadding(plaintext.decode(), mode='CMS')
            pi_label = Label(win, text='Found: ' + p)
            pi_label.place(x=80, y=390)
But it's plaintext_label is only printing the first one?